# Sorting a list into a 2D array according to X and Y

Tags: java, arrays, list, 2d

I created a Java object called bounding box which contains X and Y coordinates and can return string like (x0, y2) according to its values. I'm having a list of these boxes, I would like to turn this list into a two dimensional string array sorted according to the Y coordinate first
For example:

```
Input:
d7_x85_y30.png
d7_x86_y28.png
d7_x85_y29.png
d7_x86_y29.png
d7_x84_y29.png
d7_x84_y30.png
d7_x84_y28.png
d7_x85_y28.png
d7_x86_y30.png

Output:
[
  [d7_x84_y28.png, d7_x85_y28.png, d7_x86_y28.png], 
  [d7_x84_y29.png, d7_x85_y29.png, d7_x86_y29.png], 
  [d7_x84_y30.png, d7_x85_y30.png, d7_x86_y30.png]
]
```

I have no idea how to do that, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We can help you if not see you code, 
You should go down the line, add the code so we understand what you are asking about

Comment: First try you own! Write anything you can, then post here. Otherwise, we won't write codes for you.